# "'<' signed/unsigned mismatch "error when using functions

Tags: c++

I tried to make a switch that would go to a specific function depending on what kind of input the user put in. However, when I called the functions within each case and tried to run the code, the error that is seen in the title would come. It says that it is in line 40, where the for loop ( which prints out all menu options), is located. I can understand what the error is saying, but before I even tried using the switch and the other functions I just used the function that had the for loop within it to see if it would work, and it did. So like something concerning the addition of the switch and the addition of the other functions messed with the for loop in some way, but I just can't pinpoint how. What am I doing that is causing this error?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int Start();
    int result = Start();
    int number = select("This is the title screen. Please select an option");
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            string NewGame();
            break;
        case 2:
            string StartSave();
            break;
        case 3:
            string DeleteSave();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "That is not an available option"<<endl;
            break;
    }
    cin.get();  
}
int select(string prompt) {
    string num;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> num;
    return 0;
}
int NewGame(){
    cout << "Test"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int StartSave(){
    cout << "Test2" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int DeleteSave(){
    cout << "Test3" << endl;
    return 0;
}
int Start() {
    vector<string>title;
    title.push_back("");
    title.push_back("New Game");
    title.push_back("Start Save");
    title.push_back("Delete Save");
    for (int i = 1; i < title.size(); ++i) {
        cout << i << "." << title[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_What am I doing that is causing this error?_" 1) This is not the error. It's a warning. 2) Exactly what it says: you are comparing signed integer with an unsigned one.

Comment: You could probably make the code replicating the issue *much* smaller. And if you don't want to do that, then at least edit the code you show us *where* the line containing the error is, for examply by adding a comment on it. And while editing your question, please copy-paste the full and complete output of the compiler.

Comment: Is this really minimal? See [MCVE]

Comment: On an unrelated note, you do seem to know that vector indexes are zero-based. But that makes me wonder why you don't start your loop with index `0` instead, and don't have the first empty string? If you want to print a one-based number, then do `i + 1` for that? There are also easier ways to initialize your vector, like `vector<string> title = { "New Game", "Start Save", "Delete Save" };`

Comment: This code is riddled with actual errors. Fix all the warnings, not just those dealing with signed/unsigned.  Test your code in a debugger.

Comment: I have down-voted because that example is *much* too big.

Comment: `string NewGame();` `string StartSave();` ...  will not do what you want. Although your select returns 0 regardless of the user input so just expect `That is not an available option` to be printed.

Comment: `string num;` why is num a string?

Answer (score 0):

You have turned on `-Werror` flag which is causing this error.
Function call `title.size()` returns type of `size_type` which is a typedef of `size_t` if you change for loop as below then compilation should not fail.

```
for(size_t i= 0;i<title.size();i++) {
 // d
}
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `size_type == size_t`, but typically it is. Also, you have a typo in your loop type.

Comment: @thomas_f that's true that it's not guaranteed, but as of now, it holds true.

Comment: @thomas_f However it *is* guaranteed that a) `size_t` will be big enough; b) that `size_t` is unsigned - so the proposed code is error free (and optimal on every platform I know of).